# Pass Queryset from decorator to function

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a decorator which does the same query as the function it's attached to. Is there a way to just pass the Queryset from the decorator so I don't have to run the query twice?

**decorator.py**

```
def is_wifi_author(func):
    def wrapper(request, wifi_id, **kwargs):
        wifi = get_object_or_404(Wifi, pk=wifi_id)             # Queryset

        # Is this correct?    
        if request.user != wifi.author:
            return redirect('youshallnotpass')

        return func(request, wifi_id, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

**views.py**

```
@is_wifi_author
def edit(request, wifi_id):
    # print(request)
    wifi = get_object_or_404(Wifi, pk=wifi_id)                 # Same queryset

    # The rest of the view

    return render(request, 'app/template.html')
```

Yes, just checking if the user has access to edit the post. Any comments welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using kwargs:

```
def is_wifi_author(func):
    def wrapper(request, wifi_id, **kwargs):
        wifi = get_object_or_404(Wifi, pk=wifi_id)             # Queryset

        # Is this correct?
        if request.user != wifi.author:
            return redirect('youshallnotpass')

        return func(request, wifi_id, wiki=wiki, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


@is_wifi_author
def edit(request, wifi_id, wiki=None):
    """wiki argument is gonna be updated by the is_wifi_author decorator"""
    print('Yeii, a wiki', wiki)
    # The rest of the view

    return render(request, 'app/template.html')
```

Though I think @Ubaid answer mentions a valid point.

Comment: I also agree with @Ubaid although in this case I was creating my first custom decorator so I learned a lot in the process. Plus, I get to redirect them to wherever I want.

Comment: Great! I've used this approach to prevent the decorated function from being executed (for instance, no connection available), and I usually raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Why use a decorator when you can simply do

```
wifi = get_object_or_404(Wifi, pk=wifi_id, author=request.user)
```